# All iOS Apps suddenly no longer open on macOS Big Sur (M1), /var/log/system.log reports FairPlay decryption failed on binary?

Tags: big-sur, apple-silicon

And I have exactly zero idea where to start finding a solution. It doesn't bounce on the dock like loading, nothing at all.

Everything is updated from system updates and app store, I didn't upgrade to Monterey yet, but if nothing works that would be my next plan.

Comment: You did reboot, I assume? Is there anything relevant in /var/log/system.log?

Comment: @nohillside reboot, yes.

Comment: tried to tail -f /var/log/system.log, got this after executing an app. https://pastebin.com/wJh8d5bh also a video me executing and stuff : https://youtu.be/AQyS8oxkj_w

Comment: tried some googling, found this. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-m1-tidbits-running-ios-apps-with-ipas-running-x86-homebrew-apps-accessing-macos-recovery-and-more.2269629/page-3 but it does mention SIP. my SIP is enabled and untouched.

Comment: how could I bump this question?

Comment: have you tried to reinstall the apps and to logout/login as eleczo mentions? FairPlay is the DRM tech at apple, maybe the key for decription is corrupted

Comment: @ion it  has been turned on and off couple times. none works.

Comment: update : upgrading to monterey didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did : Reinstall my second mac mini to Monterey, then use Migration Asistant to move everything from the problematic mac mini.

I'm really stuck and don't know what else to do, and I know this might be not the solution for everyone, but maybe Time Machine would help if you really stuck with this problem too and don't have second macs around to migrate stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Did you turn off System Integrity Protection?**

Unfortunately (and to my great disappointment), disabling System Integrity Protection on Apple Silicon Macs also prevents iOS apps from launching, with the exact behavior you describe. If SIP is off, try turning it on. If you *need* SIP to be off, you unfortunately will not be able to run iOS apps on your Mac at this time.

Comment: no I didn't. SIP is not turned off, and never turned off.

Comment: It's probably pointless, but maybe try toggling it on or off? It's super strange, that log message you shared is _exactly_ what happens when you try to launch iOS apps on Macs without SIP. I feel like there's a connection there, even though I have no idea what it is.

Comment: ...frankly, you might want to just phone Apple support or go to a genius bar. Fairplay and iOS app support are opaque and really hard to debug from the outside.

Comment: disabling and enabling sip back didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I also not an expert, but rebooting and logging out and log in again in apple cloud, i to faced that issue, i done this and the app worked very well

Comment: didn't work in my case.